# Link page bounded click handlers to Footer component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

[Right now I have a Footer component with three different buttons.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8Upk.png) The onClick of two of those buttons depends on the page, and are defined in those pages. Currently I render the Footer component in the Page components separately, where the onClick functions are defined and handed as a prop, and is working great.

However I added the CSS element `max-width` to the pages, and is affecting the Footer too, which I don't want.

To solve this I need to render the Footer outside of the Page components, and in the Router component, just like the Header. But the issue is that I don't know how to link the click handlers of those two Footer buttons, which are defined in the Page components.

What would be the best way to solve this? Push the onClick functions in my Redux store?

---

Currently it's working like this:

**Router.js**

```
<div id="router-container">
    <Header />

    <Switch>
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={DashboardPage} />
        <Route path="/settings" component={SettingsPage} />
    </Switch>
</div>
```

**DashboardPage.js**

```
const DashboardPage = () => (
    <div id="dashboard-page">
        ...content
        <Footer onRightButtonClick={myDashboardPageClickHandler} />
    </div>
);
```

**SettingsPage.js**

```
const SettingsPage = () => (
    <div id="settings-page">
        ...content
        <Footer onRightButtonClick={mySettingsPageClickHandler} />
    </div>
);
```

---

But how can I get it to work like this:

**Router.js (new)**

```
<div id="router-container">
    <Header />

    <Switch>
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={DashboardPage} />
        <Route path="/settings" component={SettingsPage} />
    </Switch>

    <Footer />
</div>
```

**DashboardPage.js / SettingsPage.js**

```
const DashboardPage = () => {

    // set the onClick of the footer somehow to myDashboardPageClickHandler()

    return (
        <div id="dashboard-page">
            ...content
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: can you share the code of `myDashboardPageClickHandler` function?

Comment: Sure. `const myDashboardPageClickHandler = selectedTargetIndex > 0 ? decrementSelectedTargetIndex : 'disable';`. It checks a value and returns a Redux action or string defining the button should be disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) function of React Router to transform the Footer, like so:

```
const FooterWithRouter = withRouter(Footer);
```

then, inside the Footer component, define functions like so:

```
handleRightButtonClick() {
  const pathname = { this.props.location };

  if ( pathname === '/dashboard' ) {
    return myDashboardPageClickHandler;
  } else if ( pathname === '/settings' ) {
    return mySettingsPageClickHandler;
  }
}
```

and assign the `onClick` of the button to the return value of this function, like so:

```
<button class="right-arrow" onClick={handleRightButtonClick()}></button>
```

See if this works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However then the `myDashboardPageClickHandler` and `mySettingsPageClickHandler` functions are not defined. Those click handlers are defined in the Page component, but not in the Router.

Comment: @Potato what are the functionalities of those functions ? I guess it's something common, like navigation or sth ?

Comment: @Potato I see you are doing nothing but dispatching actions inside these functions, so just `import` those action creators here, and fire them.. i.e., copy the functionality of functions `myDashboardPageClickHandler` and `mySettingsPageClickHandler` to inside the `handleRightButtonClick` function. I think that's more clear and clean.

Comment: happy to help! consider upvoting accepted answers, too :)